# Custom filter not working angular js

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I am creating a custom filter in angular js this is my html,

```
<div class="box-body">

<div class="form-group">
    <label>Page-Title:</label>
    <input type="text" required value="" data-ng-model="title" name="page_title" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="Enter Page Title">                     
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label>Page-Alias:</label>
    <input type="text" value="@{{ title | replaceSpace}}" name="page_alias" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="Auto-Generated If Left Blank">
</div>
```

This is my angular js code

```
var app = angular.module('CustomAngular', []);
app.controller('CustomCtrl', function ($scope) {
    app.filter('replaceSpace', function () {
        return function (input) {
            return input.replace(/ /g, '-').toLowerCase();
        };
    });
});
```

The filter is not working and also I get error in the console.

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/$injector/unpr?p0=slugifyFilterProvider%20%3C-%20slugifyFilter
    at Error (<anonymous>)
```

If I use filter: infront of the filter name I donot get any errors in console but it's still not working.

```
<input type="text" value="@{{ title | filter:replaceSpace }}" name="page_alias" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="Auto-Generated If Left Blank">
```

Comment: You should not be defining the filter inside your controller, but outside of it.

Comment: I have done so but still I am getting error in my console and if I  use this , value="@{{ title | filter:replaceSpace }}"  in my alias input field I get no error but the code doesn't work i.e the filter is not doing it's work am I doing something wrong with the  binding between the two input fields @Sergiu Paraschiv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should define filter outside of controller and not use `filter:` as it has different meaning, that's the correct way to use your filter

```
<input type="text" value="@{{ title | replaceSpace }}" name="page_alias" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="Auto-Generated If Left Blank">
```

although you should either initialize model by `$scope.title = ''` or place a check in your filter to run `replace` only when input is defined, otherwise you will get JS errors

`filter:` is used to filter the array from model, and when you pass another filter to it it does nothing

Comment: if I do so I get error in my console and also the binding between the two input field does not work,  the alias input field will have {{ title | replaceSpace }} initially when the page loads . The error I get in my console is: Error: [$interpolate:interr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/$interpolate/interr?p0=%7B%7B%20title%20…D%7D&p1=TypeError%3A%20Cannot%20call%20method%20'replace'%20of%20undefined
    at Error (<anonymous>)

Comment: looks like title isn't initialised by that time then, either state in controller `$scope.title = ''` or in your filter check if value is undefined before replacing

Comment: thanks a lot update your answer so I can accept you answer as best

Answer (score 3):

You don't put filters inside of a controller, put it after your `var app` line. It's a separate thing just like controllers / directives / etc.

```
var app = angular.module('CustomAngular', []);

// Here's where it goes
// Also now any/all controllers can use it!

app.filter('replaceSpace', function () {
    return function (input) {
        return input.replace(/ /g, '-').toLowerCase();
    };
});

app.controller('CustomCtrl', function ($scope) {

});
```

Comment: well now I have the same code as yours but still I am getting error in my console and if I  use this , value="@{{ title | filter:replaceSpace }}"  in my alias input field I get no error but the code doesn't work i.e the filter is not doing it's work am I doing something wrong with the  binding between the two input fields @mcpDESIGNS